# Serving static directory in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, static-content

I have a simple rails app deployed to Heroku, and I'm trying to serve a static directory (containing an `index.html`) from the `public/demos` folder but running into a weird issue. I have `config.serve_static_assets = true` enabled in production, and if I go to `mysite.com/demos/folder/`, I can access the static page fine. But if I go to `mysite.com/demos/folder` (lacking a trailing slash), the index page loads but fails to load a bunch of linked css/js stuff located in the same directory. Is there any way around this or a better way to do it? I'm not sure what the best way is to serve static content with Rails, but this feels like a poor solution.

Comment: Could you just add a route so that the offending path redirects to the correct URL?

Comment: I'm trying but it doesn't seem to be picking up on it. I started with `match "demos/folder" => redirect("demos/folder/")` which doesn't work, and various tweaks don't work either.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you have any luck solving this?

Comment: Actually I never did. Sorry! :(